# paypal submit create popup and new tab

Tags: jquery

I' am having this weird problem with regards to paypal form, my problem is that i have several radio button as my paypal price im trying to submit it to paypal form 
using window.open + mylink in new tab, when i click the button it open in new tab read paypal form but at the same time paypal pop up appears which made my price entry duplicate i have no target in my paypal form itself. the weird thing is when i use location.href since paypal popup is appearing im expecting it with this method but it never happened. can anyone enlighten me with this. in addition with using window.open method i tried adding target="_parent" and "_self" to prevent popup still not working.

Comment: Question looks like one big run on sentence and is impossible to read

Comment: huh what do you mean?